# Mounting SATA harddisk failed

Tags: mount, hard-drive

My linux server recently broke down and I have to transfer its data out of its SATA hard disks.

I am connecting them to another linux OS using one of those docking devices that allows you to connect hard disks through a USB, like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Sabrent-External-Lay-Flat-Docking-Station/dp/B00LS5NFQ2/ref=asc_df_B00LS5NFQ2/?tag=googshopuk-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=310819177578&hvpos=1o3&hvnetw=g&hvrand=13488323029926366855&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9046360&hvtargid=pla-365069372813&psc=1).

Then I used 'fdisk' to find this connected drive, and 'mount' to mount it so I can retrieve data from it.

Fdisk successfully recognises the harddisk, as shown in the first line of the following screenshot.

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

But the mount commands both failed.

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sda /tmp

sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda /tmp
```

For both, the error messages can be seen in the screenshot below.

Can I get some advice what I have done wrong? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please don't add terminal output as screen-shots, copy and paste it as text instead, and apply proper formatting.

Comment: Normally you should have a partition on the disk .. /dev/sda1 .. this seems to be missing, so maybe the disk is broken.

Comment: that would be quite strange... these disks were in full operating order yesterday and only taken away just now for data transfer... I also have three other harddisks from the same machine, they all appear the same

Comment: I've had issues with certain brands of those USB hard drive attachment devices with SATA drives.  Sometimes only with certain drive brands (Western Digital)

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/sda` is the whole disk. You have to mount a partition, e.g. `/dev/sda1`. For example:

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sda1 /tmp
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that fdisk does not show any partitions on the drives. It seems to be the case of 'partition-less' drive, discussed here: https://superuser.com/questions/278864/cant-mount-hard-drive-ubuntu  I don't think there is easy fix in this case...